# Error "no such file or directory" when compiling with Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors, compilation

I am trying to use a Makefile to compile a couple of .c files and a couple of custom .h files to make a single executable file. however during the compilation im receiving the error that the error "No such file or directory".

Here is my Makefile, is there a possible flaw in the logic as to why the header files are being forgotten during compilation?

The error occurs on line 21 of the compilation during the `$(BIN)main.o` rule.

This is the compilation time error:

```
socs@socsvm:~/Desktop/Programs/CIS2520/root$ make
gcc -Wall -g -std=c99 -c -Iinclude -c ./src/main.c
./src/main.c:4:23: fatal error: structDefns: No such file or directory
#include "structDefns"
                      ^
compilation terminated.
makefile:21: recipe for target 'bin/main.o' failed
make: *** [bin/main.o] Error 1
socs@socsvm:~/Desktop/Programs/CIS2520/root$
```

This is the makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c99 -Iinclude

BIN = ./bin/
SRC = ./src/
INC = ./include/

$(BIN)main:     $(BIN)main.o $(BIN)book.o $(BIN)store.o $(BIN)boardGame.o
        $(CC) -o $(BIN)main $(BIN)main.o $(BIN)book.o $(BIN)store.o 
$(BIN)boardGame.o

$(BIN)book.o:   $(SRC)book.c $(INC)structDefns.h $(INC)funcDefns.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRC)book.c

$(BIN)boardGame.o:      $(SRC)boardGame.c $(INC)structDefns.h $(INC)funcDefns.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRC)boardGame.c

$(BIN)store.o:  $(SRC)store.c $(INC)structDefns.h $(INC)funcDefns.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRC)store.c

$(BIN)main.o:   $(SRC)main.c $(INC)structDefns.h $(INC)funcDefns.h
                $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRC)main.c
```

As for the file directory, the make file is outside of 3 folders, bin, src, and include. bin is where I want the object and executable to go, src is where the .c files live, and the .h files live in the include folder.

Comment: We can't  really tell without seeing all your files and directory structure. For all we know, it may be a typo.

Comment: It also helps if you show the full compilation command + error.

Comment: You list two header files as dependency, yet I don't see any flag in the actual command to provide a path so these files can actually be found. That is, CFLAGS doesn't include -I$(INC) or similar.

Comment: So you're saying the compiler has no way of connecting the header files with the actual c file itself?

Comment: It has, provided that you give the right flags to the compiler, and/or the c file has the right path to the header file. Perhaps you should read up on including header files during compilation

Comment: Sorry Im kind of confused, youre saying that the logic and pathing should be okay based on what you see here?

Comment: Please see my first two comments.

Comment: I tried to provide as much info as possible

Comment: As I expected. See my answer, but please read up on compiling with header files and include flags, with or without make. (Learning about the library location flag -L is then also useful.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the compilation command, the error and the source line given by the error:

```
gcc -Wall -g -std=c99 -c ./src/main.c
./src/main.c:4:23: fatal error: structDefns: No such file or directory
#include "structDefns"
```

it shows that `gcc` can't find the include file. It expects it in the same directory as main, but your Makefile shows it lives in `./include` (or even `../include` relative to main).

Use the `-I` flag for `gcc` together with the proper path. You can set this alongside the other CFLAGS:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c99 -Iinclude
```

should do it. 
(I may be slightly mistaken with the path. If it still fails, try variations of `-I./include` or the relative path to main: `-I../include`. But it should be the path from the directory where you issue the command, not relative to `main.c`.)

Comment: I appreciate the time and effort for the responses. Unfortunately none of the variations i tried (about 4 or 5) none of them seem to work.

Comment: @user8667363 Try `gcc -Wall -g -std=c99 -c ./src/main.c -Iinclude` by itself first. If it fails with a different error, please show that error.

Comment: It is the exact same error (i believe) the only thing different is possibly the order of the ./src/main.c and the -Iinclude, im not sure if that matters. However, I have updated the original error so you can look at it. Thank!!

Comment: @user8667363 `#include "structDefns"` should be `#include "structDefns.h"` in your source file. Header files require the full name, including extension, when using an include macro.

Comment: Amazing how something like that could get overlooked, thank you so much!